# Defining a right-linear grammar for a language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language

Would someone please be able to confirm if my right-linear grammar is correct for the language L?

$L := {b(ab)^na^m | n, m \ge 0}$

> Grammar $G(b(ab)^na^m)$
>   
>  Terminal a,b
>   
>  Non-terminal S, S1, S2 
>   
>  Start symbol S
>   
>   Productions: 
>   
>  S -> abS 
>   
>               S -> ab
>   
>               S1 -> aS1
>   
>               S1 -> a
>   
>               S2 -> b

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not correct e.g take the word $abab\notin \mathcal L$ because the word must start at $b$

$S\to abS \to abab$

Comment: Ah right I see, thank you.